# Egit at Eclipse: can I see changes in files on commit screen?

Tags: eclipse, egit

I need preview like in IntelliJ IDEA. Strange that this is not the default behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes very strange. I solved that using the **Git Staging** view.

Go to Window -> Show view -> Other, and select **Git Staging**.

[image]

There you can see all you need in order to do a proper commit, **unstaged changes**, **changes**, even conflicts. And of course you can do a **commit** or **commit and push** directly.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you - this much better - I even can set hotkey for this window - strange but my shortcut for commit screen not working.

Comment: The shortcut for commit is Ctrl+# so you need to press Ctrl+Shitf+3.

Answer (score 0):

I think the *idea* in Eclipse is to do commits from synchronization view and to be consistent between different team providers. The former comes from old times when CVS and SVN ruled. Nowadays it seems to be a cumbersome way to do it.
Heck, even SVN team providers allow you to revert changes from the Java view while from EGit you can either reset the whole working copy or you need to go to Synchronization view and use cryptic Overwrite option for a single element. Of course changes in files that you're asking about are there.